# How to align data of a richtextbox into columns

Tags: c#

This is an example of my data I want to align.

[image]

I read about

`richTextBox1.Text = "\t1\t2\t3\t4";
richTextBox1.SelectionTabs = new int[] { 100, 200, 300, 400 };`

but I can't make any sense of it. The description at msdn is a bit too vague. What the `{ 100, 200, 300, 400 }` mean? I think it's pixel size but how to I modify it to fit my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed the `SelectionTabs` is an array in which each member specifies a tab offset, in pixels. The number represents the width from the left margin.

Example:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionTabs = new int[] { 100, 200, 300, 400 };
```

The text after the first tab will be alligned 100px from the left margin.
The text after the second tab will be alligned 200px from the left margin.
...
These settings apply to each row.

This is why your `RichTextBox` control must have a specific `Width` defined. For that width you need to define 5 tabs.

Also, keep in mind that `SelectionTabs` property applies only to selected text. This is why you need the extra code which first selects the entire text, and than sets the SelectionTabs property.

Here is an example that works in your scenario:

```
richTextBox1.Width = 580;
            richTextBox1.Text =
                "24,34\t1228\tC:\\14035/61439\tD:\\399175/415186\t01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11\t0 1 2 3 " +
                "58,05\t4017\tC:\\5610/61439\tD:\\396629/415186\t10 11 12 13 14 15\t0 1 2";
            richTextBox1.SelectAll();
            richTextBox1.SelectionTabs = new int[] {50, 100, 200, 320, 530};
            richTextBox1.AcceptsTab = true;
            richTextBox1.Select(0, 0);
```

Comment: After playing with it for a while i figured it out. One last thing, if i set the selectiontab at the beginning i think i don't have to select the text.

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // richTextBox1.Width = 480;
        richTextBox1.Text =
            "value1\tvalue2\tvalue3\tvalue4\tvalue5\tvalue6\n" +
            "value1\tvalue2\tvalue3\tvalue4\tvalue5\tvalue6\n" +
            "value1\tvalue2\tvalue3\tvalue4\tvalue5\tvalue6\n" +
            "value1\tvalue2\tvalue3\tvalue4\tvalue5\tvalue6";

        richTextBox1.SelectAll();
        //------------------------------------- value1
        //------------------------------------------ value2
        //----------------------------------------------- value3
        //---------------------------------------------------- value4
        //--------------------------------------------------------- value5
        richTextBox1.SelectionTabs = new int[] { 50, 100, 150, 200, 250 };
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        richTextBox1.AcceptsTab = true;
        richTextBox1.Select(0, 0);
    }
```