# How to align formatted richtextbox into Columns NET c#

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox

I have a data like a bill,
ID | Item | Total Price
I need to print them like a table, but using richtextbox.
I found some code but the problem is that I have to align numbers from right to left, and item text from Left to Right.

like this

```
ID  Item                                                     TotalPrice
1   Monitor TV 10 cm                                            100.50
1.1 HP DESKJET 3630 /3636 MULTIFUNKTIONS WIFI DRUCKER            49.50
1.2 Canon PIXMA MG5750 Tintenstrahldrucker Multifunktionsgerät   99.60
2   Dell UltraSharp U2715H 69 cm (27 Zoll) 16:9                 610.82
3   15.6' (39,62cm) HP 250 G5 I5/8GB/1TB/W10Home                508.02
```

but  I got this:

```
ID  Item                                                     TotalPrice
1   Monitor TV 10 cm                               100.50
1.1 HP DESKJET 3630 /3636 MULTIFUNKTIONS WIFI DRUCKER            49.50
1.2 Canon PIXMA MG5750 Tintenstrahldrucker Multifunktionsgerät                       99.60
2   Dell UltraSharp U2715H 69 cm (27 Zoll) 16:9                    610.82
3   15.6' (39,62cm) HP 250 G5 I5/8GB/1TB/W10Home                                       508.02
```

### My code in c# like this:

```
 foreach (DataRow dr_pos in GenerateData().Rows)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += dr_pos[0].ToString().PadRight(5, ' ') 
                                    + dr_pos[1].ToString().PadLeft(0, ' ') 
                                    + dr_pos[2].ToString().PadLeft( 40 , ' ')  ;

               richTextBox1.Text +=   Environment.NewLine;
            }

 private DataTable GenerateData()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                table.Columns.Add("Column " + i.ToString(), typeof(string));
            }           
            {
                // Header
                DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
                dr[0] = "ID";
                dr[1] = "Item";
                dr[2] = "TotalPrice";
                table.Rows.Add(dr);

                // Data 0
                dr = table.NewRow();
                dr[0] = "1";
                dr[1] = "Monitor TV 10 cm";
                dr[2] = "100.50";
                table.Rows.Add(dr);

                // Data 1
                dr = table.NewRow();
                dr[0] = "1.1";
                dr[1] = @"HP DESKJET 3630 /3636 MULTIFUNKTIONS WIFI DRUCKER  ";
                dr[2] = "49.50";
                table.Rows.Add(dr);
                // Data 2
                dr = table.NewRow();
                dr[0] = "1.2";
                dr[1] = @"Canon PIXMA MG5750 Tintenstrahldrucker Multifunktionsgerät";
                dr[2] = "99.60";
                table.Rows.Add(dr);

                // Data 3
                dr = table.NewRow();
                dr[0] = "2";
                dr[1] = @"Dell UltraSharp U2715H 69 cm (27 Zoll) 16:9 ";
                dr[2] = "610.82";
                table.Rows.Add(dr);

                // Data 4
                dr = table.NewRow();
                dr[0] = "2";
                dr[1] = @"15.6' (39,62cm) HP 250 G5 I5/8GB/1TB/W10Home";
                dr[2] = "508.02";
                table.Rows.Add(dr);

                return table;
        }
        }
```

I read many articles and solutions but they didn't work as I wish.

Thanks in advance

Comment: change link of the duplicate url

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465560/how-to-align-data-of-a-richtextbox-into-columns

Comment: no, I tried also to resize the control, 
I really did many works,,

Comment: this link I tried it is a problem of aligning  numbers from right to left

Comment: You could find the length of the largest string which in your case would be line 1.2 and use this to calculate howmuch each line had to be padded. Just subtract the length of the current string from this value. Should work.

Comment: Don't use `PadRight` and `PadLeft`.  Check this out: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?545102-Formatting-Fixed-width-Text-Output.  Note that any method that allows you to format a `String` can be used in the same way, i.e. you don;t have to use `StringBuilder.AppendFormat`.

Comment: the size is a bad idea, because some char like "1" is less in space with another char like "W".

Comment: @jmcilhinney   http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?545102-Formatting-Fixed-width-Text-Output  not good, if I change the Name to be long it will not work

Comment: Um, yes good.  It will work perfectly well if you do it properly.  If you think it won't work then you're thinking of doing it wrong.  If I understand your rather vague protest correctly, all you have to do is to make sure that you specify a "column width" that is at least as big as the longest value you want to display in that "column". Simple.  If you mean something else then please say what you actually mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use PadRight on the second field. There is just a padleft(0), then padleft(40) on the number can't be right. For example:

```
richTextBox1.Text += dr_pos[0].ToString().PadRight(5, ' ') 
                                + dr_pos[1].ToString().PadRight(40, ' ') 
                                + dr_pos[2].ToString().PadLeft(5, ' ')  ;
```

Btw you have to set a monospaced font for the textbox in order to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that demonstrates the use of the principle I provided in the comments above:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var table = GenerateData();
            var maxNameLength = table.AsEnumerable().Max(row => ((string) row[1]).Length);
            var formatSpecifier = "{0,-5}{1,-" + (maxNameLength + 2) + "}{2,10}\r\n";

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format(formatSpecifier, row[0], row[1], row[2]));
            }
        }

        private DataTable GenerateData()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                table.Columns.Add("Column " + i.ToString(), typeof(string));
            }

            // Header
            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "ID";
            dr[1] = "Item";
            dr[2] = "TotalPrice";
            table.Rows.Add(dr);

            // Data 0
            dr = table.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "1";
            dr[1] = "Monitor TV 10 cm";
            dr[2] = "100.50";
            table.Rows.Add(dr);

            // Data 1
            dr = table.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "1.1";
            dr[1] = @"HP DESKJET 3630 /3636 MULTIFUNKTIONS WIFI DRUCKER  ";
            dr[2] = "49.50";
            table.Rows.Add(dr);
            // Data 2
            dr = table.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "1.2";
            dr[1] = @"Canon PIXMA MG5750 Tintenstrahldrucker Multifunktionsgerät";
            dr[2] = "99.60";
            table.Rows.Add(dr);

            // Data 3
            dr = table.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "2";
            dr[1] = @"Dell UltraSharp U2715H 69 cm (27 Zoll) 16:9 ";
            dr[2] = "610.82";
            table.Rows.Add(dr);

            // Data 4
            dr = table.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "2";
            dr[1] = @"15.6' (39,62cm) HP 250 G5 I5/8GB/1TB/W10Home";
            dr[2] = "508.02";
            table.Rows.Add(dr);

            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

I tested that exact code and it worked for me.

Comment: I donot know why the fuked boy down vote me, it seems to be a dummy person